# Is it safe to remove this LED from that motherboard?

Tags: led, resistors, circuits, motherboard, sata

So, I've bought this SATA case from internet but it has a really bright light on it and annoys me. I don't haver any kind of tool to manage any electronic component, and neither have electrical tape to hide this light, so I would like to know if it is safe and it will continue working if I remove it with a knife or something like that (touching only the light, ofc)

[image: photo of the circuits]

[image: complete photo]

I want to remove the LED2.

Comment: It's a resistor and LED, so yes you could desolder either to get rid of the light (or even change the resistor to d it) but black tape would be a lot less work.

Comment: apply nail polish or hobby paint to the LED to change its color ... apply in thin layers until desired brightness is achieved

Comment: the nail polish did not work, but then i tried with a nail Clipper and i successfully broke the LED and it stopped working without affecting the circuit, even though it is stills there and with a bit of nail polish and a bit on the motherboard. but its working, so it does not bothers me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a black Sharpie and apply some physical dimming to the led. it may take several applications.

Other brands of permanent marker will also work.  the ink is non-conductive and will not alter the electrical perfomance of the circuit.

Removing the LED will probably work and not compromise the performance of the circuit, but there is an increased risk especially if you're a klutz like me.

Comment: will try it out!

Comment: had no sharpie and nail polish didnt work, só I clipped the LED with a nail Clipper! it is still on the motherboard and with a bit of nail polish on the LED and the MB, but its working Fine and no brightness anymore! even though i was not very delicated haha